# Using JavaScript to Loop through APEX Application Items

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am working on Oracle APEX, where i have an interactive report to display columns and rows in a tabular form. In the report I have used "apex_item" { each having it's item_id } for most editable columns.

Now, there are three columns, one with the pre-defined read-only value, one where the new value is to be entered and another where the difference between the two would be displayed.

I am not able to write a javascript code to make the above work for all the rows in the report corresponding to those 3 columns. It is only working for the first row for me.

Below is the sample example:

```
1. APEX_ITEM.TEXT(9,abc, p_item_id=>'p09') 
2. APEX_ITEM.TEXT(9,xyz, p_item_id=>'p10')
3. APEX_ITEM.TEXT(9,def,p_attributes =>'readonly', p_item_id=>'p11')

-- document.getElementById("p10").value --> This is only referring to the
                                            value for the first row for that column (p10).
```

I need item_id 'p11' to reflect the difference of the values of p10 and p09 when i enter the value in p10. Need it to work across all rows for that column.

Comment: Please post relevant code and point to specific error. Even though you have tried your best to explain the scenario, looking at the relevant piece of code helps more.

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 Have edited the question with parts of code. Can you help me further?

Comment: Do all rows of that column have the same id?? p10??

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 That particular column has the id-> p10. Now, that column has many rows ofcourse, the question is on how to access each row of that column.

Comment: The column has multiple rows but they have the same id. And when you select elements by id, only 1 element is returned.

Comment: Exactly, that is what is happening. How to select the other elements of the other rows?

Comment: I didn't quite get it ... why don't you use the editable **Interactive Grid** instead?

Comment: @Littlefoot I am using an Interactive Report. Can't shift to an Interactive Grid as the entire application is using the Interactive Report.

Comment: If you say so; though, I must admit that I don't understand such a reason. As if you (plural) deliberately make your life, as a developer, harder than it deserves to be. I just wanted to share my opinion, you do whatever you find appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using jQuery here. First add a common classname to the rows of each column. I am here providing same classname as the id.

```
$('[id]').each(function() {
    var ids = $('[id="p09"]');
    if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
        $('#' + this.id).addClass('p09');
        }
    var ids = $('[id="p10"]');
    if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
        $('#' + this.id).addClass('p10');
        }
    var ids = $('[id="p11"]');
    if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
        $('#' + this.id).addClass('p11');
        }
    });
```

Now you can start a loop over elements like:-

```
$(".p9").each(function(){
    $(this).val() = $(this).siblings(".p11").val() - $(this).siblings(".p10").val();
});
```

Comment: Let know if you are not able to get it done or have more issues.

Comment: I didn't quite get you. Could you please explain a little more? How would i access the elements of each row in the loop and do the calculation? 

Eg. p10[i] + p09[i] = p11[i] ---> where i refers to the row for each column.

Comment: I assume that the columns and rows are like table cells. If this does not work then please check the relative DOM path of p9 wrt p10 and p11 and implement accordingly

Comment: Sure. Still trying it out. Will let you know.

Comment: @Arpan Roy Okay

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I solved the issue. I am using *'PThis'* which is basically a *this* pointer that refers to each cell in my report. I am using that to find out which row does that particular cell belong to and using that row number i am accessing the other cells where my computation will take effect.

Looking at this function, the code should be self-explanatory.

```
   function change(pThis)    
    {

        var row = pThis.id.split('_')[1];

        var xyz= parseFloat(document.getElementById("xyz"+row).value) ;
        var abc= parseFloat(document.getElementById("abc"+row).value) ;
        var def= parseFloat(xyz)-parseFloat(abc);

        def= Math.round(def*100)/100; 
        document.getElementById("def"+row).value = def;

    }
```

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 Take a look at this, when you have time! Wouldn't have arrived at this solution without your help! :)